# How to show a message only the first time an app is launched?

Tags: iphone, ios4

Is there an easy way to have an alert appear only the first time an app is launched, or will I have to do it manually by making a BOOL and having it set to FALSE after it's run the first time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sounds easy enough...

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

if(![defaults boolForKey:@"hasBeenLaunchedBefore"]) {
  //Show alert
  [defaults setBool:YES forKey:@"hasBeenLaunchedBefore"];
  [defaults synchronize];
}
```

Comment: I can't find hasBeenLaunchedBefore in the documentation.  Am I missing something?

Comment: That is just a random string I used for a key in that example. You can call it MickeyMouse if you want. It just checks whether the bool stored in the defaults for that key is YES, if not, it sets it to YES (and you show your alert).