# Is there any delegate that fires when I run the iphone application for the first time?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I need to track the download of a certain iphone application. I tried a lot and found out that we could track it from the AppStore. But i need to track that from my application itself. So please help me to identify the method that fires when the application starts for the first time. Thanks.

Comment: A duplicate of [How to show a message only the first time an app is launched?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4209673/how-to-show-a-message-only-the-first-time-an-app-is-launched) Sorry, did not notice before answering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no specific method that fires only on the 1st application launch. You can set a flag in user defaults on application start - so if the flag is not present then that will mean that application launched for the 1st time:

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication *)application { 
    if (![[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] boolForKey:@"AlreadyLaunched"]){
        // First launch logic

        [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"AlreadyLaunched"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: It won't help you track downloads, it'll only track how many times the app has been run from a "fresh" install.   You get a new "fresh" install every time the user deletes and re-syncs the app and then runs it.

Answer (score 1):

> But i need to track that from my application itself.

No.

But if you really want to do this you could use something like this:

```
BOOL hasUsedSpyWareFunctions = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"SpyWareKey"];
if (!hasUsedSpyWareFunctions) {
    [self spyOnUser];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"SpyWareKey"];
}
```

if you are a Pro in spying you only set the key to YES if the method returned successfully (ie a network connection could be established)

Answer (score 0):

There’s no such an event, at least not one that I know of. But what you want can be trivially done using `NSUserDefaults`. Simply check for some boolean flag and if it’s not there, it’s a first run and you can set the flag:

```
NSString *const AlreadyRunKey = @"already-run";
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
if (![prefs boolForKey:AlreadyRunKey]) {
    [prefs setBool:YES forKey:AlreadyRunKey];
    [prefs synchronize];
    // do whatever else you want
}
```